# how to pass variables in NuSMV

Tags: model, logic, model-checking, nusmv

I'm working on an exam project in the software NuSMV with the following specification:

> A famous cook opens a sushi bar in Urbino. the bar has a single round
> table with N chairs where client can seat. The cook spends the whole
> serving time preparing meals which  he serves on plates and places on
> the first available spot on the table. Clients arrive at the  bar and
> either take a seat at the table or wait for an available seat. 
>
>  The following configuration variables are used: 
>  private sem
> empty = N; // values in [0..N]
>  private sem full = 0; // values in
> [0..N]
>  private sem ready = 0; // values in [0..N]
>  private sem
> mutex = 1; // values in {0,1}
>  private int[] bar; // N positions
> initialized to 0 in a constructor
>  private int front = 0;
> private int rear = 0;
>  private bool endservice = false; 
>  
> the sem type is a semaphore used to deny or give access. it can be
> decremented  if it's positive using P (wait) and incremented using V
> (signal). the semaphores  empty, full and mutex are used to handle the
> seats of the table while ready is used to handle the table itself. the
> vector bar describes the positions of plates on the table (0 meaning
> no plate there). The variables front and rear describe  points of
> access to the cook and the clients. The boolean endservice determines
> if the cook can finish serving the table.

so far I've made 3 modules to emulate the cook, clients and the table(which functions like how a shared object would function in multithreading)

here is the module for the cook:

```
MODULE cook (table)
    
    VAR
        state       : {working, serving, served, idle, finished};
        endservice  : boolean;

    ASSIGN
        -- The state determines at what cycle the cook is in it's working phase with the options being:
        -- 1. Working:   The cook has no access to the mutex yet but it would like to deliver a plate to the table.
        -- 2. Serving:   The cook is currently placing a plate on the table. The cook has the mutex.
        -- 3. Served:    The cook has finished placing a plate on the table and the mutex can be released. 
        -- 4. idle:      There are no clients on the table that don't have a plate.
        -- 5. finished:  Serving has finished, only reachable by setting endservice to true, which puts the cook 
        --               immediately in the state finished from any other state. 
        -- A diagram of states would look like this:
        -- +-----------------------------------------------+
        -- |                                               |
        -- | -> [WORKING] ------------------> [SERVING]    |
        -- |     |   ^                            |        |
        -- |     |   |                            |        |
        -- |     |   |                            |        |
        -- |     |   +----------- [SERVED] <------+        |
        -- |     |   |               |            |        |
        -- |     |   |               |            |        |
        -- |     |   |               |            |        |
        -- |     |   +----- [IDLE] <--------------+        |
        -- |     |             |     |            |        |
        -- |     |             |     |            |        |
        -- |     |             V     V            |        |
        -- |     +----------> [FINISHED] <--------+        |
        -- |                                               |
        -- +-----------------------------------------------+

        init(state)      := working;
        next(state)      := case
                            (endservise = true)                                              : finished; -- finished service.
                            (table.semReady = N)    & (!endservice)                          : idle;     -- no plates to fill.
                            (table.semReady != N)   & (table.semMutex = 0) & (!endservice)   : working;  -- mutex request.
                            (table.semReady != N)   & (table.semMutex = 1) & (!endservice)   : serving;  -- inside critical section.
                            (state = serving)       & (!endservice)                          : served;   -- notify end critical section.
                            TRUE                                                             : state;
                            esac;

        -- The variable endservice is used to tedermine when the cook should exit his work cycle and finish execution. 
        -- Currently it is set to always continue working. In a future implementation the cook will stop working when all
        -- clients have finished eating. 
        init(endservice) := false;

        -- The variable endservice is used to tedermine when the cook should exit his work cycle and finish execution. 
        -- Currently it is set to always continue working. In a future implementation the cook will stop working when all
        -- clients have finished eating. 
        init(endservice) := false;
```

Here is the module for the table which handles all the variables mentioned in the specification above:

```
MODULE table (cook, client)
    VAR
        -- We are emulating a table with 4 spaces to sit and eat sushi, therefore we need a an array to store if each of the 4
        -- spots to sit at have a plate in front of them or not. 
        bar: array 0..3 of boolean;

        semEmpty: 0..4;         -- The number of empty seats.
        semFull:  0..4;         -- The number of clients with a plate.
        semReady: 0..4;         -- The number of clients without a plate.
        semMutex: {0,1};        -- A mutex to ensure mutual exclution of the array bar.

        front:    0..3;         -- the first seat with no plate in the bar.
        rear:     0..3;         -- the first empty seat at the bar. 
    ASSIGN
        init(bar[0])     := 0;
        next(bar[0])     := case
                            (cook.state = serving)  & (front = 0)           : 1;       -- add plate to the table on spot 1
                            (client.state = eating) & (client.spot = 0)     : 0;       -- remove plate from the table on spot 1
                            TRUE                                            : bar[0];
                            esac;

        init(bar[1])     := 0;
        next(bar[1])     := case
                            (cook.state = serving)  & (front = 1)           : 1;       -- add plate to the table on spot 2
                            (client.state = eating) & (client.spot = 1)     : 0;       -- remove plate from the table on spot 2
                            TRUE                                            : bar[1];
                            esac;

        init(bar[2])     := 0;
        next(bar[2])     := case
                            (cook.state = serving)  & (front = 2)           : 1;       -- add plate to the table on spot 3
                            (client.state = eating) & (client.spot = 2)     : 0;       -- remove plate from the table on spot 3
                            TRUE                                            : bar[2];
                            esac;

        init(bar[3])     := 0;
        next(bar[3])     := case
                            (cook.state = serving)  & (front = 3)           : 1;       -- add plate to the table on spot 4
                            (client.state = eating) & (client.spot = 3)     : 0;       -- remove plate from the table on spot 4
                            TRUE                                            : bar[3];
                            esac;

        -- The semEmpty variable contains the number of empty seats at the sushi bar.
        init(semEmpty)   := N;
        next(semEmpty)   := case
                            (client.state = seated)    : semEmpty - 1;        -- A client has entered the sushi bar.
                            (client.state = left)      : semFull + 1;         -- A client has left the sushi bat.
                            TRUE                       : semEmpty;
                            esac;

        -- The semFull variable contains the number of clients with a plate at the table. 
        init(semFull)    := 0;
        next(semFull)    := case
                            (client.state = eating)    : semFull - 1;         -- A client has started eating.
                            (cook.state = served)      : semFull + 1;         -- The cook has finished serving a plate.
                            TRUE                       : semFull;
                            esac;

        -- The semReady variable is used to see how many clients are seated at the table but don't have a plate of food.
        init(semReady)   := 0;
        next(semReady)   := case
                            (client.state = seated)    : semReady + 1;        -- A client has entered the sushi bar.
                            (cook.state = serving)     : semReady - 1;        -- The cook has placed a plate on the table. 
                            TRUE                       : semMutex;
                            esac;

        -- The semMutex variable is used as a lock for mutual exclusion on the array variable: "bar". It switches state depending
        -- on whether either the cook or client are in a state where they require the mutex lock or are able to release said lock.
        init(semMutex)   := 0;
        next(semMutex)   := case
                            (cook.state = working)   & (semMutex = 0)       : 1;  -- the cook wants to modify "bar", obtain mutex.
                            (cook.state = served)    & (semMutex = 1)       : 0;  -- the cook has finished modifying "bar", release mutex.
                            (client.state = seated)  & (semMutex = 0)       : 1;  -- the client wants to modify "bar", obtain mutex.
                            (client.state = left)    & (semMutex = 1)       : 0;  -- the client has finished modifying "bar", release mutex.
                            TRUE                                            : semMutex;
                            esac;

        -- The front variable is used to determine where the first open spot is for a cook to place a plate on the table.
        init(front)      := 0;
        next(front)      := case
                            (bar[0] = 0)                                                : 0;
                            (bar[0] = 1) & (bar[1] = 0)                                 : 1;
                            (bar[0] = 1) & (bar[1] = 1) & (bar[2] = 0)                  : 2;
                            (bar[0] = 1) & (bar[1] = 1) & (bar[2] = 1) & (bar[3] = 0)   : 3;
                            TRUE                                                        : front;
                            esac;

        -- The rear variable is used to determine where the first empty seat is at the bar for a new client to sit.
        init(rear)       := 0;
        next(rear)       := case
                            (semEmpty = 0)                                              : 0;
                            (semEmpty = 1)                                              : 1;
                            (semEmpty = 2)                                              : 2;
                            (semEmpty = 3)                                              : 3;
                            TRUE                                                        : rear;
                            esac;
```

Finally here is the table module:

```
MODULE client (table, spot)
    VAR
        state       : {new, seated, eating, left};

    ASSIGN
        -- The state determines at what cycle the client is in it's eating phase with the options being:
        -- 1. New:       The client has entered the sushi bar and is looking for a place to sit.
        -- 2. Seated:    The client has found a place to sit and is waiting for his food to arrive.
        -- 3. Eating:    The client has food and is able to eat said food.
        -- 4. left:      The client has finished his food and has left the sushi bar.
        -- A diagram of states would look like this:
        -- +-----------------------------------------------+
        -- |                                               |
        -- | -> [NEW] -----------------------> [SEATED]    |
        -- |                                      |        |
        -- |                                      |        |
        -- |                                      |        |
        -- |      +-------------------------------+        |
        -- |      |                                        |
        -- |      |                                        |
        -- |      V                                        |
        -- |    [EATING] ----------------------> [LEFT]    |
        -- |                                               |
        -- +-----------------------------------------------+
        init(state)      := new;
        next(state)      := case
                            (table.semEmpty != 4)                                            : seated;   -- There is an empty spot.
                            (table.bar[spot] = 1)                                            : eating;   -- The client is eating.
                            (state = eating)                                                 : left;     -- The client finished eating.
                            TRUE                                                             : state;
                            esac;
```

I hope the comments make it easy to read what i'm trying to do. Currently i'm working on the final `main` module, which as far as I understand connects all other modules together and set's up how they interact. currently it looks like this:

```
-- Main module(unfinished)
MODULE main
    VAR
        t  : table(cook, client)
        c  : cook(table)
        cl : client(table)
```

A friend of mine told me that you only need 1 of each module to link them together in the main module, even if you want multiple instances of a module. For example let's say we want to emulate 8 clients eating at the sushi bar, we till only need 1 client variable like I've created in my `main` module.

however if you look at the implementation of my client module you see that apart from the table module I pass another parameter: `spot` which stores the number of the seat the client wishes to sit on. My rational is that, because a client can only eat if it has a plate, it needs to check if the seat it's sitting on has a plate in front of it. to do so it needs to keep track of the seat it's sitting on. that's where I planned to use the `spot` variable. Now you may have guessed it but I'm not particularly handy with this kind of programming(model checking) and I don't know if this implementation is the right way, but what I do know is that I don't know how I pass the spot variable to each client I want to emulate. How is this done? Am I on the right track?

Comment: One has to instantiate N instances of a module if one wants N instances of a module. Perhaps your friend has a clients module that models an arbitrary number of clients and not just one as in your case.

Comment: You can use the dot notation to pass fields of a module, something like t.front should do. Notice that you're giving a label to each seat, but the exercise doesn't require you to track which seat a client uses so you may want to simply count the number of free/occupied chairs. That should simplify your model.